# What is the idiomatic way to express "we have no power to run this machine"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

> **[power](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/power)**  7  [noncount] a : energy that can be collected and used to
>   operate machines
>
> electrical/nuclear/solar/wind/battery power
>
> The car's engine yields more power while using less fuel.
>
> — see also horsepower, manpower
>
> b : the electricity that people use
>
> We lost power during the storm.
>
> Do you know how many watts of power your refrigerator uses per day?

---

Whenever a learner like me looks up a new word in a dictionary, he or she expects to see some very common examples that most people use.

For example, when I looked for the word "**power**", the first thing that came in my mind was "**how to express that we have or don't have power to run a machine**"

But some dictionaries don't have this kind of common examples.

So, let's say "**you took your laptop / radio to a library & you plugged its cable into a socket & there was no power, what you you say in this situation**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You took your laptop / radio to a library & you plugged its cable into a socket & there was no power - **what would you say in this situation?**

I would say that *the socket is dead*, or isn't working.

This is because I would first assume that the problem was with the socket. We tend to know if there is a *power cut* because lights go off, air-conditioning/heating goes off etc.

In a power cut we would say exactly that - there has been a power cut - or that there is no power in the building.